# ERROR: "brownie test --network mainnet-fork" , error: no test ran

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, ganache, brownie

No tests run but I see activity on the alchemy project page so it seems something is working...

Error when running command ~ "brownie test --network mainnet-fork"

for

FreeCodeCamp:full-blockchain-solidity-course, lesson 7, timestamp 6:29:20 https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ?t=23360

test_lottery.py file:

```
from brownie import Lottery, accounts, config, network
from web3 import Web3


def test_get_entrance_fee():
    account = accounts[0]
    lottery = Lottery.deploy(
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["eth_usd_price_feed"],
        {"from": account},
    )
    lottery.tx.wait(1)
    print(lottery)
    assert lottery.getEntranceFee() > Web3.toWei(0.015, "ether")
    assert lottery.getEntranceFee() < Web3.toWei(0.022, "ether")
```

Lottery.sol file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract Lottery {
    address payable[] public players;
    uint256 public usdEntryFee;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal ethUsdPriceFeed;

    // enum LOTTERY_STATE {
    //     OPEN,
    //     CLOSED,
    //     CALCULATING_WINNER
    // }
    // LOTTERY_STATE public lottery_state;

    //0
    //1
    //2

    constructor(address _priceFeedAddress) public {
        usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
        ethUsdPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress);
        // lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        // $50 minimum
        // require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN);
        // require(msg.value >= getEntranceFee(), "Not enough ETH!")
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 price, , , ) = ethUsdPriceFeed.latestRoundData();
        uint256 adjustedPrice = uint256(price) * 10**10; // 18 decimals
        // $50, $2,000 / ETH
        // 50/2,000
        // 50 * 100000 / 2000
        uint256 costToEnter = (usdEntryFee * 10**18) / adjustedPrice;
        return costToEnter;
    }

    function startLottery() public {}

    // require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED);

    function endLottery() public {}
}
```

brownie-config.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
networks:
  mainnet-fork:
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419'
```

Error:

```
jamesgish@Jamess-MacBook-Pro smartcontract-lottery % brownie test --network mainnet-fork
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

================================================================ test session starts =================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.2, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/jamesgish/demos/smartcontract-lottery
plugins: eth-brownie-1.16.4, hypothesis-6.21.6, xdist-1.34.0, web3-5.23.1, forked-1.3.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                     

Launching 'ganache-cli --accounts 10 --fork https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/tdby0yIyVKmUtwrdGi35fGkWV0TpjWs6 --mnemonic brownie --port 8545 --hardfork istanbul'...
Terminating local RPC client...
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 269, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 322, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_collection(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 333, in pytest_collection
INTERNALERROR>     session.perform_collect()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 641, in perform_collect
INTERNALERROR>     hook.pytest_collection_finish(session=self)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 55, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     gen.send(outcome)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/test/managers/runner.py", line 258, in pytest_collection_finish
INTERNALERROR>     brownie.network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/network/main.py", line 50, in connect
INTERNALERROR>     rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 95, in launch
INTERNALERROR>     raise RPCConnectionError(cmd, self.process, uri)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/exceptions.py", line 41, in __init__
INTERNALERROR>     f"\n\nCommand: {cmd}\nURI: {uri}\nExit Code: {proc.poll()}"
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'poll'

=============================================================== no tests ran in 10.51s ===============================================================
```